# How to change the background image of live USB?

Tags: live-usb, desktop-background

I have created a live system using SystemBack.

When I boot from the live USB, the background image is of SystemBack theme, but I want to change it into another image.

How would I do this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)